# Why in upload time, other pages were be slow or can not be open?

Tags: asp.net, performance, iis, upload, web-config

I used this code on web.config for **RequstLength** of upload page:

```
  <location path="Upload.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <httpRuntime executionTimeout="60000" maxRequestLength="1572864" requestPathInvalidCharacters="" requestValidationMode="2.0" relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true" enableVersionHeader="false"/>
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
      <security>
        <requestFiltering>
          <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1610612736"/>
        </requestFiltering>
      </security>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
```

and when I open a page of my site at the time of upload,pages dont open, **till upload finishes**.
How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Is this issue related to maximum worker process of iis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's related to **enableSessionState** of requested page which I send file to upload.
When I used it as **enableSessionState="ReadOnly"** in @page directive level, it solved.
https://forums.asp.net/t/2105020.aspx?Why+in+upload+time+other+pages+were+be+slow+or+can+not+be+open+